# Find tangent between point and circle Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Ok some i'm a bit rusty on my trigonometry.

Essentially I'm trying to make a sort of spotlight in canvas. I'm trying to maintain a 9 degree angle which is why this is a little tricky. Here's my fiddle so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/uq8fe/

```
it's a bit long please refer to the fiddle /\
```

Pretty close, but i need the tangent points on the circle so i can draw a triangle between those two points and the mouse, so i looks like a nice smooth beam.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Inscribed_angle_theorem4.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aInscribed_angle_theorem4.svg)

Above is essentially the diagram and formula i need to implement. I need  point T and S. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code to calculate tangents:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uq8fe/7/)

```
    //Calculate Tangents
    var pointDistance = {
        x: beamCenter.x - mousePos.x,
        y: beamCenter.y - mousePos.y,
        length: function () {
            return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y)
        }
    }

    var radius = getDist(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y) / 2;
    //Alpha
    var a = Math.asin(radius / pointDistance.length());
    //Beta
    var b = Math.atan2(pointDistance.y, pointDistance.x);
    //Tangent angle
    var t = b - a;
    //Tangent points
    var T1 = {
        x: beamCenter.x + radius * Math.sin(t),
        y: beamCenter.y + radius * -Math.cos(t)
    };

    t = b + a;
    var T2 = {
        x: beamCenter.x + radius * -Math.sin(t),
        y: beamCenter.y + radius * Math.cos(t)
    }
```

Comment: wooo nailed it! Thanks so much