# How to connect a line to circle (not the center) using java fx

Tags: java, javafx, graph

I am using javafx
I wont to Connect a line to 2 circle the connection must be to the surface of the circle not the center

And when the circle move the line connect to the best point in the circle. 
when connecting, the line and the circle must not overlap

Thank you

**Edit**

The solution i am looking for require that

1. the line intersect with the circle  so the tangent is not the solution
2. if the line virtually continue it must intersect with the center of the circle

Comment: See [Find a tangent point on circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351746/find-a-tangent-point-on-circle) and maybe [Find tangent between point and circle Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117776/find-tangent-between-point-and-circle-canvas)  (The second one is javascript, though).  

If you are still having trouble try to explain what you have done and what failed/didn't work as planned.

Comment: So take the line to the center until the point of intersection? 

It is not clear what the problem is. Please try to go as far as you can and explain where exactly you have the problem.

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to do it in javafx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the position is only modified using the `centerX` and `centerY` properties, this can be done by simply adding listeners to those properties.

The ends of the line can be determined by using the center of a circle translated a distance equal to the radius in direction of the other center.

Note that this doesn't take the stroke widths into account:

```
public static Point2D getDirection(Circle c1, Circle c2) {
    return new Point2D(c2.getCenterX() - c1.getCenterX(), c2.getCenterY() - c1.getCenterY()).normalize();
}

public static void connect(Circle c1, Circle c2, Line line) {
    InvalidationListener startInvalidated = observable -> {
        Point2D dir = getDirection(c1, c2);
        Point2D diff = dir.multiply(c1.getRadius());
        line.setStartX(c1.getCenterX() + diff.getX());
        line.setStartY(c1.getCenterY() + diff.getY());
    };
    InvalidationListener endInvalidated = observable -> {
        Point2D dir = getDirection(c2, c1);
        Point2D diff = dir.multiply(c2.getRadius());
        line.setEndX(c2.getCenterX() + diff.getX());
        line.setEndY(c2.getCenterY() + diff.getY());
    };
    c1.centerXProperty().addListener(startInvalidated);
    c1.centerYProperty().addListener(startInvalidated);
    c1.radiusProperty().addListener(startInvalidated);

    startInvalidated.invalidated(null);

    c2.centerXProperty().addListener(endInvalidated);
    c2.centerYProperty().addListener(endInvalidated);
    c2.radiusProperty().addListener(endInvalidated);

    endInvalidated.invalidated(null);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Circle c1 = new Circle(100, 100, 50, null);
    c1.setStroke(Color.BLUE);

    Circle c2 = new Circle(200, 200, 50, null);
    c2.setStroke(Color.RED);

    Line line = new Line();

    connect(c1, c2, line);

    Pane pane = new Pane(line, c1, c2);

    // demonstrate update during movement
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(c1.centerXProperty(), 100)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(c1.centerYProperty(), 100)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(c1.centerXProperty(), 300)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(c1.centerYProperty(), 50)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(c2.centerXProperty(), 200)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(c2.centerYProperty(), 200)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(c2.centerXProperty(), 100)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(c2.centerYProperty(), 100))
    );

    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

    timeline.play();

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

If you use larger stroke widths, you may need to take them into account...

Note that the whole problem becomes a lot easier, if the fill of the circles with fully opaque paint and don't modify the blend effects, since the circles after the line will result in the circles being drawn on top of the line in that case, which means connecting the centers would suffice.

Comment: thank you for your response. the code don not compile because **getDirection** is not defined

Comment: @targat: Missed a method during copy & paste... Sorry. Added it now.